# Laravel MongoDB Lookup with Condition: Fetch employee list along with number of task completed by each employee

Tags: mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb, laravel-mongodb

I am using [Laravel MongoDB library](https://github.com/mongodb/laravel-mongodb) (formerly know as [Laravel Jenssegers MongoDB](https://github.com/mongodb/laravel-mongodb/tree/3.9#laravel-version-compatibility) library).

This is my employees collection

```
{
    _id         : {$oid: 2ndkj3720eA83b24},
    name        : 'Employee1',
    status      : 'a',
    deleted_at  : null
}
```

This is my task collection:-

```
{
    _id              : {$oid: 893jfo2ok01398190},
    name             : 'Task 1',
    employees        : [
                         {$oid: ae2nvg6788eA83b24},
                         {$oid: be09gh56701398190},
                         {$oid: bf0e28bfi45202bc0}
                       ],
    complete_status  : 'c',
    status           : 'a',
    deleted_at       : null
}
```

The employees column in task collection is an array of object ids of employees.

This is how I fetch employee list:-

```
$aggergateCondition     = array(
                            array(
                                '$lookup'   => array(
                                                'as'            => 'taskList',
                                                'from'          => 'tasks',
                                                'foreignField'  => 'volunteers',
                                                'localField'    => '_id'                                                
                                            )
                            )
                        );
$employeeListing        = Employee::raw(function($collection) use($aggergateCondition){
                                        return $collection->aggregate($aggergateCondition);            
                                    });
```

But now I want to fetch only those tasks whose complete_status is 'c'.

How can I do that?